# jQuery Fix page scrolling to top after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im just building a basic lightbox type plugin to suit the needs of a project im building. It basically just allows the user to click on an image on the page and the image appear in the lightbox, the problem is when i click on the close button on the lightbox,the script causes the window to shoots to the top of the page.

This is unwanted behavior because if i have been scrolling on 1000+ pictures for example i wouldnt want it to just undo all that scroll just by closing a picture.

**Here is my fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/w407wdrv/

**Here is my code:**

```
<style>
    body, html {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .flavius-modal-bg {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .flavius-img-section {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .flavius-options-section {
        background: white;
        height: 20%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .flavius-img-preview {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        min-width: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="flavius-modal-bg">
    <div class="flavius-img-section">
        <img class="flavius-img-preview" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvWoePDuMwoKkA2f6LIIgWg7nlR5wq5pJwM8DJucMvlEF94wEV" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flavius-options-section">
        <a class="close-modal-bg" href="#">Close Me</a>
        <a href="#">Some button clicked</a>
    </div>
</div>

<img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/644/Ferrari_Formula_1_f1_448686_1334x750.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://insanelyi.com/uploads/gallery/album_102/gallery_1_102_91150.jpg" alt="">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('img').on('click', function(){
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('img.flavius-img-preview').attr('src', currentImg);
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close-modal-bg').on('click', function(){
        $scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'none');

        setScrollPosition($scrollTop);
    });

    function setScrollPosition($scrollTop)
    {
        $('body').scrollTop($scrollTop);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: replace your close anchor to this`<a class="close-modal-bg" href="javascript:void(0);">Close Me</a>
`

Comment: Rather than using `javascript:void(0)`, if you're going to link to something, actually link to something!  Consider linking to an image ID in the anchor fragment, then use the history API to watch for hash changes and handle them in your code.  Then back/forward work properly, a URL can be shared direct to what was clicked on, and your links are normal links that work with alternative devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javascript:void(0);` to achieve your req.

Please find below working snippet

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('img.flavius-img-preview').attr('src', currentImg);
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close-modal-bg').on('click', function(){
        $scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'none');

        setScrollPosition($scrollTop);
    });

    function setScrollPosition($scrollTop)
    {
        $('body').scrollTop($scrollTop);
    }
```

```css
body, html {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .flavius-modal-bg {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .flavius-img-section {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .flavius-options-section {
        background: white;
        height: 20%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .flavius-img-preview {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        min-width: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flavius-modal-bg">
    <div class="flavius-img-section">
        <img class="flavius-img-preview" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvWoePDuMwoKkA2f6LIIgWg7nlR5wq5pJwM8DJucMvlEF94wEV" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flavius-options-section">
        <a class="close-modal-bg" href="javascript:void(0);">Close Me</a>
        <a href="#">Some button clicked</a>
    </div>
</div>

<img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/644/Ferrari_Formula_1_f1_448686_1334x750.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://insanelyi.com/uploads/gallery/album_102/gallery_1_102_91150.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

I update your jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/w407wdrv/1/
The problem is on `<a class="close-modal-bg" href="#">Close Me</a>`, by replacing `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0);"` it will prevent the page to scroll on top.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just the ash that you use for the href:

```
<div class="flavius-options-section">
    <a class="close-modal-bg" href="#">Close Me</a>
    <a href="#">Some button clicked</a>
</div>
```

1.Remove the ash from the href of the closing anchor

```
<div class="flavius-options-section">
    <a class="close-modal-bg">Close Me</a>
    <a href="#">Some button clicked</a>
</div>
```

2.Add a class to style the link

```
.close-modal-bg{
     cursor:pointer;
     text-decoration: underline;
     color:blue;
}
```

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('img.flavius-img-preview').attr('src', currentImg);
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close-modal-bg').on('click', function(){
        $scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'none');

        setScrollPosition($scrollTop);
    });

    function setScrollPosition($scrollTop)
    {
        $('body').scrollTop($scrollTop);
    }
```

```css
 body, html {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .flavius-modal-bg {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .flavius-img-section {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .flavius-options-section {
        background: white;
        height: 20%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .flavius-img-preview {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        min-width: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    .close-modal-bg{
         cursor:pointer;
         text-decoration: underline;
         color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flavius-modal-bg">
    <div class="flavius-img-section">
        <img class="flavius-img-preview" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvWoePDuMwoKkA2f6LIIgWg7nlR5wq5pJwM8DJucMvlEF94wEV" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flavius-options-section">
        <a class="close-modal-bg">Close Me</a>
        <a href="#">Some button clicked</a>
    </div>
</div>

<img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/644/Ferrari_Formula_1_f1_448686_1334x750.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://insanelyi.com/uploads/gallery/album_102/gallery_1_102_91150.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

change your clsoe function to this,

```
 $('.close-modal-bg').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('.flavius-modal-bg').css('display', 'none');

        setScrollPosition($scrollTop);
    });
```

As in [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp),

The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.

For example:

1.Prevent a submit button from submitting a form
2.Prevent a link from following the URL
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is what I thought also, just a thing to add : It was jumping top because it was acting as an anchor (#), but since you don't have one defined/specified it is going top. Try it to see if you define `<a class="close-modal-bg" href="#image1">Close Me</a>` will have the same result. Interesting huh?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()`:

```
$('a.my-class').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // do your thing
})
```